# Comparison of an Arduino's performance?

Tags: performance

How does an AVR-based Arduino's CPU performance compare to a vintage PC (Apple II, PC-XT, TRS-80, et.al.)?

How many megaflops of number crunching can one get out of an AVR-based Arduino?

Comment: take a look here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=40901.0 There is reference to 30k float divisions per second, so it is 0.03MFLOPS. Also, this topic was brought up before, please google before asking: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/535/how-computationally-powerful-is-an-arduino-uno-board

Comment: The topic wasn't searchable in **this** forum, and one can't seem to dup a Q across stackexchange sites without admin help.

Comment: this is not a forum and google searches across interwebs since 1998

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I just ran some **really** old benchmarks on a LightBlue Bean (AVR 328p Arduino at 16 MHz).  The Bean ran the Byte Sieve benchmark slightly slower than a VAX 11/780.  The Bean also ran some of my old floating point computations about 2X faster than the 11/750 (this VAX model has no FPU to be fair to the AVR).  That puts the Bean's math performance at somewhere around 70 kFLOPs (with few divides in the mix).  A DEC VAX is several times faster than vintage 8-bit personal computers, an IBM PC-XT being roughly 1/3 to 1/2 a VAX "MIP" in benchmark performance, with an Apple II being slower still.

Comment: An 11/780??!? Those were the days :)